# Manage paths when deploying R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, web-deployment

I need some advice on how to take a working app from your local machine onto a web deployment.

I tried deploying an App to Shinyserver.io, but I have path errors. It cannot find my utilities code in `utils-fun.R`.

**Error message**

> The application failed to start.
>
> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
>    could not find function "GetSettings"

For example: my `server.R` is in an App directory

```
library(shiny)
code...

source("../code/utils-fun.R")

... rest of code
```

How do you help RShiny know what it *needs to take with* when it is deploying?
Should the structure of your directories rather be more like this.

> -Root or App directory
>
> ui.R
>    Server.R
>
> > -- code (as subdirectory where my functions are)
> >
> > -- data (rds and data files)

With everything in one directory, underneath the ui.R /server.R files?

I see from [using-source-in-shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864611/using-source-in-shiny) that I need to add `local = TRUE` to my source but is that all you need?

Thanks I would appreciate any sage advice of how you implement R Shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tidiness I keep my source files in a folder called "files" alongside ui.r and server.r. Since the working directory for a shiny app is the folder where ui.r and server.r are kept you can use source("files/script.r").

Comment: Thanks. Do you use `local = TRUE` as well? Are there any environment "tricks/traps" I must watch out for?

Comment: No, I never use local=TRUE and haven't had problems yet. Under http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html you can find the scoping rules for shiny and under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409267/environments-in-r-shiny my take on setting local and gloabl variables incase this of relevance for you.